# How can I download blob data stored by Google Chrome browser while watching a video?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, blob

I am using a website which has short video clips (10-15 seconds). I want to download those video clips but when I Right Click -> Copy Video Address, it copies a blob link (blob:https://www.getstoryclips.com/3055dd66-9764-45fe-a1c5-f932ec57ae25). Now I have done some research on blob links and understand that chrome uses blobs to save data on the client side locally.

Which naturally brings me to this problem, If chrome has already downloaded those videos in the form of blobs, how can I get those videos from chrome's local blob storage? I tried searching Google Chrome's local directories but did not find anything there. Does Google Chrome restrict access to its blob storage or am I missing something else here?

Comment: That blob URL is virtual. It's produced by MediaSource API so it's not usable elsewhere. You'll need to get the original video/audio chunks and feed them into a compatible js player library. There might be solutions for that already. Otherwise you'll have to reverse-engineer the site's approach yourself.

Comment: So a couple of questions:

1- Isn't the blob data stored on my browser locally?
2- If yes to number 1 then, is that blob data accessible?
3- If yes to number 2 then, is that data useable as a video?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question when I downloaded a zip from Mega.nz who also store it as a blob. For some reason however after I chose where to save it to, it didn't materialise there. There was no file? Instead of downloading the entire zip again I searched the browser directory for large files (since it was quite large) and found only one, the exact size of my intended zip.

It was in \profile\data\File System\002\p\00\ and was called "00000000" I copied it and renamed it to a zip and I could view it's contents fine. So the blob files ARE indeed stored locally until you clear the websites cache.

So you might be able to clear your entire browsers cache then watch one of those videos then search around in the "File System" folder and see if you can find it. Then rename it to .mp4 or .ts or whatever.

Comment: This is true for Opera but as I found out today it is NOT true for Google Chrome on Mac OSX. I'm yet to find the location of downloaded Mega files